# How can we add time durations HMS formats in lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

Though there are a few questions and a few workaround answers too, but I cannot find direct methods to add hours/minutes/seconds objects?

Let's consider through an example. I have a vector `a` having time time intervals in HH:MM:SS format.  I can parse it easily using `lubridate::hms` as shown below

```
a <- c("38:03:24", "6:50:58", "0:31:54", "8:13:51")
hms(a)

[1] "38H 3M 24S" "6H 50M 58S" "31M 54S"    "8H 13M 51S"
```

But how can I sum this vector?

```
> sum(hms(a))
[1] 187
```

`as.period`, `seconds` etc. cannot help.  So How can I add up all the values in the given vector without converting it to first seconds then modulo division then minutes then modulo division....

my expected output would be like `54H 8M 7S`

I have another issue, when I add each element separately, it does so in the required format, but not correctly? why? and How to correct it?

```
> hms(a)[1] + hms(a)[2]
[1] "44H 53M 82S"
```

clearly `82S` should be converted to `22S` and `53M` to `54M`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a <- c("38:03:24", "6:50:58", "0:31:54", "8:13:51")

td <- as.period(seconds(sum(as.numeric(hms(a)))), unit = "hour")
# [1] "53H 40M 7S"
sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', td$hour, td$minute, td$second)
# [1] "53:40:07"
```

Comment: Can we apply sum outside of all functions, i.e. in last?

Comment: give it a try :)